# Combinations with Repetition. Possible combinations with third colour ball absent.

Tags: statistics, combinations

I am stuck on a combinations problem and was wondering if anyone could walk me through.

The question is as follows:

"Consider you have 11 balls, 5 are red, 4 are blue and 2 are green and you wish to draw 3.  In how many of the possible combinations are there balls of two colours with the third colour absent?"

Comment: What do you mean "the third color absent"?

Comment: Sorry it wasn't clear.  This was how the question was worded in the text.

It means you would take three balls and only have 2 different colours.  There would be one colour of ball that was not selected.

For example, you might take 3 balls - 2 reds and one blue. 

But you would not count the combination if one of each colour is selected - 1 green, 1 blue and 1 red.

Comment: Ways that avoid green: ${5+4 \choose 5}.$ Then figure out ways that avoid blue, and ways that avoid red. Add. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Hi Bruce, yes, thanks for your time.  Thus, I am looking for the number of combinations that you can have which avoid a blue ball along with the number of combinations that avoid a green ball and the number which avoid a red ball?  

Is there a method calculate this in one step?  Or shall segregate the problem as indicated in your reply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try counting the opposite; in how many combinations are there all 3 different balls? You have to draw 1 red ball (5 ways to do it since you choose 1 object out of possible 5), 1 blue ball (4 ways) and 1 green ball (2 ways). Thus there are 5*4*2 = 40 ways to draw all 3 different balls. Since there are (11 choose 3) ways to draw any 3 balls out of 11, by the complement principle the answer should be (11 choose 3) - 40 = 125.